# Using Bootstrap list-group to go horizontal at the medium break

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

Using Bootstrap, I have a list I want to display vertically on large devices, but then display horizontally on the medium break point. I can see how to do it the other way around, but can't find anything on this. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you give us some details or code so we can help you with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give ul the classes `flex-row` and `flex-lg-column`. Check out the snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <ul class="list-group flex-row flex-lg-column">
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked great to start, but I've now got a new issue. If there are quite a few things in the list, how would I get that to section off after so many items? Like, say I've got 12 items in the list, how would I make them restructure into three rows of 4, without screwing up the vertical list on larger views?

Comment: I can help you if you can give more details or share the code as an example. But for now there will be 3 col. We will insert the list items four by four. Just like this: .row>.col*3> ul>li*4(This is emmet. Please write this in your code editor and press tab key). I think this might work.